# Why adding transform to fixed parent changes child width?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed child div inside fixed parent div. When I set the child width to 100% it is set either to 100% width of the window **OR** 100% of the parent width if I add transform: translate to the parent div.

parent div css:

```
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  // transform: translate(-50%, 0);

  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: red;
}
```

child div:

```
#inner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Now #inner is 100% width of the screen.
Uncommenting the transform line makes it 100% of parent. What's going on?

1. http://codepen.io/kokojr/pen/wWvbrz
2. http://codepen.io/kokojr/pen/KMKLQX

**UPDATE:**

1. Ok, I didn't notice that at first but actually it's not only width that changes, position becomes relative too.
2. For anyone who wonders, that works down the way as well. If you add an `#inner-inner` div with fixed position it will position itself rel. to `#outer` unless you add a transform to `#inner` as well. It's `#inner` then that becomes the context for fixed children. Reminds me of this very interesting article: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Seems that `transform` crates a distinct stacking context / environment where the #inner "fixes" absolutely in relation to the transformed parent. Interesting.

Comment: In the past, I think the CSS WG resolved that fixed elements should also establish a containing block for fixed descendants. But it seems they changed their mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [CSS 2.1 - Definition of "containing block"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) and [CSS Position 3 - Definition of containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#def-cb),

> If the element has `position: fixed`, the containing block is
>   established by the [viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport) in the case of continuous media or
>   the page area in the case of paged media.

However, that changes when you add transforms to some ancestor. From [CSS Transforms 1 - The Transform Rendering Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering),

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value
>   other than `none` for the transform results in the creation of both a
>   stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a
>   containing block for fixed positioned descendants.